# How to overwrite FOS user bundle form labels

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

I have a hard time overwriting labels that the FOS user bundle for Symfony2 uses.

I'm already overwriting the Form class, but there is no option for elements like "setOption", only getters.

I could just remove an element and than add it again with the proper label but this seems like an overkill. Is there any nice way of overwriting options on form elements, or just translation keys, perhaps?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to overwrite Form classes.

Copy/paste `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.xx.yml` files in your `app/Resources/translations` directory (with the same directory structure and the same file name) and redefine translations to your convenience.

edit: As told by @mario-johnathan, overriding translations is not part of bundle inheritance. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#translations for official documentation

Comment: Actually I had to copy it into app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translation instead of my bundle dir to make it work,

Comment: Note that you have to enable translations in your framework's `config.yml` for this to work, i.e.:


framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale" }

Comment: And note that you need to clear the cache (php app/console cache:clear) to reload the translations if you changed it.

Comment: I'm using SF2.8 and the correct path to put the file is app/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.xx.yml

Comment: @MarioJohnathan Thank you! Works!

Comment: What would be the correct path with SF3.2? I've added two more fields to the Registration Form (name and last name), the fields saved the info correctly but I'm using a placeholder inside fields.html.twig with this code: `placeholder="{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"` but the translation for my new two fields are empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As already said you can put your translations files in :
`app/Resources/translations`

But if you override it in your parent bundle (`src/MyAppBundle/Resources/translations`) or in any other bundle, make sure to **load your bundle after** the overridden bundle in your Kernel :

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        ...
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new MyAppBundle\MyAppBundle(),
        ...
    ];
...
}
```