# Hyperlinks in FOSUserBundle form label

Tags: forms, symfony, customization, label

So I've searched, googled, asked and even consulted the stars, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this specific problem.

When overriding an FOSUserBundle form,(specifically the Change Password form, but generally any other FOSUserBundle form), is there a way to set part of the field **label** to be a hyperlink?

Does the question make sense? I could elaborate if it doesn't.

**The goal**

I would like to have resultant HTML to look like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="fos_user_resetting_form_has_acceptedtos">I agree to the <a href='/tos/'>Terms Of Service</a>.</label>
    <input id="fos_user_resetting_form_has_acceptedtos" type="checkbox" value="1" name="fos_user_resetting_form[has_acceptedtos]">
</div>
```

**What I've tried. . .**

I have added the `has_acceptedtos` field to the User.php Entity and hooked into the controller, as per [the instructions](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md). And I have [customized the field labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473329/how-to-overwrite-fos-user-bundle-form-labels) successfully.

Unfortunately, the following syntax, unsurprisingly, doesn't work either:

```
# app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml
# ...
# Password change
change_password:
    submit: Change password
    has_acceptedtos: I agree to the <a href='/tos'>Terms Of Service</a>.
...
```

I have even attempted to override the template, in an attempt to artificially create a label that would appear in the vicinity of the checkbox via css.  Didn't work out too well.

Other than re-writing the entire FOSUserBundle to generate my own forms, can this even be accomplished?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: How does your generated html looks?

Comment: Exactly the same as I intend, with the exception of the <a> tags around the words 'Terms of Service'

Comment: As Peter answered below, you need to override your template and use `raw` filter when rendering your label.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a combination of [custom form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) and the [Twig "raw" method](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) to accomplish this.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417510/symfony-2-twig-how-not-to-escape-field-value-used-with-backbonejs-symfony-2) that deals with a quite similar issue.